# how to check if any pending animations are there in jquery fx queue

Tags: jquery

i am doing something like this in

```
$("somethreedivs").animate(

    { //move the three divs to the left},1000


 ).promise().done(function()
     {
        //hide the leftmost div
        //introduce a new div in the right


     });
```

I wanted a check before the above specified animation "if any of the animation is incomplete, dont attempt to do the specified effect"

```
if("what condition to be given here/how to check the animation queue"){
    return;
}
```

> I want the above "if check" to be put before my animate code, so as to
>   avoid animations if any animation is pending. The whole idea is a new
>   animation should be triggered only if the previous animation effect is
>   complete. What I understood from specifying "queue:false" any new animation triggered wont wait for the previous animation to complete, thats not my scenario.

Comment: Not really sure what you are getting at here, but you can call a function within the actual `.animate(function() { // do effect }).promise().done(function() { // do something else });`

Comment: Also, you can put it in a function and perform each animation recursively after the animation is complete.  I will need to know exactly what you intend to animate...  Are you animating 1 div at a time (to the left)?  And you don't want the divs to animate at the same time?  If so, than we can pass the elements index into the function as a parameter and use that for the animation.  Would need to see how the DOM is setup though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if($(":animated").length)
```

Comment: Thanks, I never thought it would be this simple. Jquery is tryly "write less,do more"

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
if($(somethreedivs).is(':animated').length>0){
  //return from here
  }
$("somethreedivs").animate(

{ //move the three divs to the left},1000

).promise().done(function()
 {

    //hide the leftmost div
    //introduce a new div in the right
 });
```

Comment: i wanted the check to be before the animation effect. your check logic is inside the callback method. Thanks for replying.

Comment: that if condition will always return true. Your checking if any animated element exist inside the animate method itself.